# find basis for kernel and columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let A =

```
    1  4 −3 0

    −2 −7 5 1

    −4 −5 7 5
```

Find bases for Ker(A) and Col(A).

I understand finding the basis for col(A) is just finding RREF and the basis is the columns that have pivot positions. But not sure how to find ker(A) and its basis.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the linear system $Ax=0$

Comment: thats what I did for col(A) lol. is the question asking for a basis for 2 things or 1 thing? what would be the difference in finding basis for ker(A) and col(A)?

Comment: The kernel of $A$ is the set of solutions of $Ax=0$, which is not at all the column space of $A$.

Comment: ah ok, so how does one find the basis for column space?

Comment: is it just the pivot positions of a non-augmented matrix using just coefficient matrix?

Comment: Yes, user, a basis for the column space is the columns of $A$ that are pivot columns in the reduced row-echelon form.